# How can I access variables set by node_view_multiple() in node.tpl.php or a preprocess function?

Tags: theming

I'm using this code In Drupal 7:

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
$build += node_view_multiple($nodes);
```

The `node_view_multiple()` function adds a variable to the build:

```
$build['nodes'][$node->nid]['#weight'] = $weight;
```

How can I access this variable either in the node.tpl.php template file, or otherwise in `hook_preprocess_node()`?

Comment: Your question wasn't really intelligible as it was so I rewrote it...if I haven't understood what you were trying to ask please feel free to revert it back. Although if you do that I'd recommend sorting out the formatting problems while you're doing it